# Chrome: "The exception unknown software exception 0xe0000008"

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Chrome crashed saying:

"The exception unknown software exception 0xe0000008"

What could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: What's your system version? Have you tried to uninstall Chrome and install other Chrome version? Perform a clean boot to avoid some software and service.https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows Meanwhile, I consider that you could use the command "sfc /scanow" to scan system files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your commit charge (virtual memory) may be at 100%.
In the ressource monitor your can see this.

[Picture of virtual memory in resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjrUi.png)

How to change your virtual memory:
https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2016/05/10/how-to-manage-windows-10-virtual-memory.aspx